Nexus update to a new server
I have a Nexus repo running on a docker instance, version 3.15.
I'm trying to migrate it to a more recent version (3.68.1).
AFAICS, my old version does not permit to "export" data, to then import it into the new server.
I tried to copy the "blob" folder in /nexus-data from the old to the new instance, I can see in the Nexus console the "Blob Stores" menu showing my data, but I can't see my images in a repository.
I had first tried to copy the full "nexus-data" folder, but it failed to start the Nexus instance.
Can you tell me how to (and if I can) populate my repositoryfrom the "Blob" ?
Regards

Sorry for the noise : I had created a new repository with a different name.
SOLUTION : create a repo with the exact samen name.
Then create a task "Reconcile component database from blob store", run it. Et voilà !
